# Does Play read all supported languages messages files while booting

Tags: playframework-2.0

Kindly confirm if Play 2.0 framework read all supported messages file at the time of running or compilation. As my current project support around 20 languages and boot is taking lot of time.This is happening because of messages files.I just want to know that play framework read all messages files at the time of compilation. If yes,do we have any alternative to make it read only the set language message file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message file contents are read in at **runtime**, specifically at application startup. Message files are not parsed or processed in any way at compilation time.

I recommend that you take a look at the `MessagesPlugin` class at the bottom of [this source code file](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala) for a better understanding of how Play processes message files. The basic algorithm is as follows:

```
On application startup:
  load the contents of the default messages file into a map
  for each locale l specified in the application.langs configuration value
    load the contents of the messages.l file into a map
  consolidate these maps into a single (locale -> file contents) super map
```

If you feel that supporting a large number of locales is impacting the performance of your application, you can test out this hypothesis by reducing the number of languages you support in your `application.langs` configuration setting.

Comment: If I am reducing the number of supported languages in application.conf , performance is getting enhanced . So is there any way by which I can make play read only one message file without changing the list of supported languages ??